# Edit XML via HTML Form (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, forms

I'm trying to create a form that will let you edit the contents of an xml tag. i currently have a form.php:

```
<?php
$data=simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');
$welcome=$data->item->name;
?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="name"><?php echo $welcome ?></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data=simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');
$data->item->name=$_POST['name'];
$handle=fopen("welcome.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$xml->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

and welcome.xml:

```
<welcome>
    <item>
        <name>$welcome</name>
    </item>
</welcome>
```

when i press submit it doesn't save what's entered, it just refreshes the page and deletes whatever the value in the xml file was before..

**UPDATE**

The form works now, but I've added a reset button, i need it to clear the xml file so it only has the `<welcome>` tags. I've changed `$data->item->name=$_POST['welcome'];` to `$data='';` but it deletes the text and keeps the tags still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with simplexml.

To read data from xml:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');

$welcome = $data->item[0]->name;
```

And to write data:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');

$data->item[0]->name = $_POST['welcome'];

$handle = fopen("welcome.xml", "wb"); 
fwrite($handle, $xml->asXML());
fclose($handle);
```

EDIT:
For the question in the comment:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data=simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');
$data->item->name=$_POST['name'];
$handle=fopen("welcome.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$data->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}

$data=simplexml_load_file('welcome.xml');
$welcome=$data->item->name;

?>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="name"><?php echo $welcome ?></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: one last thing, i've added another button to remove the `<item><name></name></item>` parts so the xml file just has `<welcome>` in it, but it just clears the text, not the tags, I changed this `$data->item->name=$_POST['welcome'];` to this `$data='';`

Comment: use unset($data->item); 
instead of $data='';