# Edit XML file with PHP form

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that I want to be able to edit using a form.

student.xml

```
<students>
  <student>
    <name>Jane Doe</name>
    <email>email@email.com</email>
    <school>School Name</school>
    <coach>Coach Name</coach>
  </student>
</students>
```

Basically my form is set up like this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
  <input name="school" id="school" type="text">
  <input name="coach" id="coach" type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$data=simplexml_load_file('student.xml');

$data->student->name=$_POST['name'];
$data->student->school=$_POST['school'];
$data->student->coach=$_POST['coach'];

$handle=fopen("student.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$data->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}

$data=simplexml_load_file('student.xml');

?>
```

How can I use a form to edit multiple nodes in one form?  Right now it changes all the nodes to the same as the first one.

Edit: Code is updated. It all seems to be working now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sidenote: This `<form action= method="post">` should read as `<form action="" method="post">` if running from inside the same file. If not, do `<form action="yourfile.php" method="post">`

Comment: Sidenote #2: You also have a missing semi-colon in `$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_file('student.xml')` - Plus, your submit button doesn't hold the same name as your conditional statement.

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12514292/ might be of help.

Comment: deleted my answer, not useful anyway, for editing, what i would do is convert the xml into an array, present a CRUD like table, the usual stuff, (the unique identifier is the array key of student node) in the table there is a link called `edit`, and from there edit that particular key/node on the array, then write it on a file, of course its not good when you have like 10,000 entries.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That did it!  I matched my file structure and was able to edit the file.  Thanks.  I saw that question but when I first looked it didn't appear to be what I was looking for.

Comment: It's actually only working for one.  I'm going to edit the code above.

Comment: So, what you posted in an edit works? ... but not the the second one, correct? @N13Design

Comment: @N13Design Take a look at my answer whenever you get a chance. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

***Sidenotes:*** However, am unsure why you're using `$data->student->coach=$_POST['coach'];` instead of `$data->item->coach=$_POST['coach'];`

**(Also consult footnotes)** - Important.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

 $data=simplexml_load_file('student.xml');

 $data->item->name=$_POST['name'];

 $data->item->school=$_POST['school'];

 $data->item->coach=$_POST['coach'];


$handle=fopen("student.xml","wb");
fwrite($handle,$data->asXML());
fclose($handle);
}

$data=simplexml_load_file('student.xml');
$welcome=$data->item->name;
$school=$data->item->school;
$coach=$data->item->coach;

?>

<?php

echo $welcome . " ";
echo $school . " ";
echo $coach . " ";

?>

<form method="post">

Coach name: <br>
<input type = "text" name = "coach"> Present value in file: <?php echo $coach; ?>
<br><br>

School name: <br>
<input type = "text" name = "school"> Present value in file: <?php echo $school; ?>
<br><br>
Name: 
<br>
    <textarea name = "name"><?php echo $welcome; ?></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Which produced (after editing it also using different values):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<welcome>
    <item>
        <name>name 1</name>
    <school>St-Peter</school>
<coach>Robert</coach>
</item>
</welcome>
```

Editing using different values produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<welcome>
    <item>
        <name>name 2</name>
    <school>St-Andrews</school>
<coach>George</coach>
</item>
</welcome>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

In order for it to work properly is, that an existing file with the following structure must already exist.

```
<welcome>
    <item>
        <name>A name</name>
    <school>A school name</school>
<coach>A coach's name</coach>
</item>
</welcome>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are using `<form action= method="post">`. It must be changed to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Also, if you want to link to a file, it must be like `<form action="afile.html" method="post">`.